# Ruby constants in singleton methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

I have a Ruby C extension; I call that class FooC defined in `ext/foo/foo.c`, in that file I have

```
void Init_foo(void)
{
  VALUE cFoo = rb_const_get(rb_cObject, rb_intern("FooC"));
  :
  rb_define_const(cFoo, "BAR", 7);
  :
```

That is included in the "Ruby part" of the extension in `lib/foo.rb` like

```
class FooC ; end

require 'foo/foo'

class Foo < FooC
  class << self
    def puts_bar
      puts BAR
    end
    :
  end
  :
end
```

Unexpectedly, I get an error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:Foo>::BAR
```

I was expecting that Ruby would not find `BAR` in the `Foo` namespace, but would then search `FooC` where it would find it.  Strangely, if I use `Foo::BAR` or `self::BAR`, the error goes away, and a similar usage in a `Foo` *instance* method gives me no errors at all.

Anyone have an idea as to why I need this seemingly redundant qualification of constants in singleton methods?

[edit]

Following the interesting answer below, I confirm that this qualification is *not* needed in a proper class method:

```
class Foo < FooC
  def self.puts_bar
    # no NameError here
    puts BAR
  end
  :
end
```

rather than a instance method of the eigenclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking the constant up in the eigenclass of `Foo`, not in the `Foo` itself. Start with figuring out what’s what without any [c](/questions/tagged/c) bindings.

```rb
class FooC; end
class Foo < FooC
  BAR = 42
  puts "Foo: #{self}, DEF: #{const_defined?(:BAR)}"
  class << self
    def puts_bar
      puts "Foo.class: #{self} DEF: #{self.class.const_defined?(:BAR)}"
      puts self.class.const_get(:BAR)
    end
  end
  def puts_bar
    puts "Foo.class: #{self} DEF: #{self.class.const_defined?(:BAR)}"
    puts self.class.const_get(:BAR)
  end
end
```

And see how it works:

```
#  Foo: Foo, DEF: true

[2] pry(main)> Foo.puts_bar
#⇒ Foo.class: Foo DEF: false
#   NameError: uninitialized constant Class::BAR
#   from (pry):8:in `const_get'

[3] pry(main)> Foo.new.puts_bar
#⇒ Foo.class: #<Foo:0x0000556e174b91c0> DEF: true
#   42
```

Constants are made visible within **instance functions** by looking up the class’ constants. `#<Class:Foo>` in the error message you’ve got is explicitly pointing out to that.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking that this was something to do with C, and I find that defining a "proper" class method rather than an instance method in the eigenclass, then this odd behaviour doesn't happen.  Still not entirely clear to me why though ... I've edited the question a little.

Comment: `class << self` introduces a new scope, `def` does not. That said, `BAR` is visible in your edited version because of a closure.

Comment: Welcome back to ruby. :) Technically speaking shouldn't `BAR=42` be in `FooC` based on the C extension code?

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks :) indeed, I was trapped by all these `cFoo`, `FooC` naming collisions. Still, to access the constant from the eigenclass, as in the example, one should fully qualify it, while the instance has an unqualified access to it.

Comment: Agreed the impact is the same although `class Foo < FooC; class << self; def puts_bar; const_get(:BAR); end; end; end;` would work but just `BAR` will not (as is already shown in OP)

Comment: Thank-you both for these helpful comments, clearly my mental-model of the Ruby eigenclass needs some work (not for the first time), I'll study it some more.

Comment: As you guys both said, neither `const_get` nor `self.class.const_get` would work in the first method. But note that `self.const_get` works perfectly.